# multithreaded os.system calls don't run simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, os.system

The following code takes 5 seconds to run rather than the expected 1 second:

```
import threading, os

def wait_one_second(): 
    print(f"{threading.current_thread().name}: Hi!")
    os.system('sleep 1')
    print(f"{threading.current_thread().name}: Bye!")

for _ in range(5):
    thread = threading.Thread(target = wait_one_second)
    thread.start()
```

Do calls to os.system block the GIL or something? The problem is resolved when I replace the os.system call with a `subprocess.call` call, but the latter opens up a new process which kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: It's probably the GIL. The [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) can be used to get around that.

Comment: This works for me in ~1 second as expected, can you provide any additional detail to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on a M1 Mac by any chance?

I ran the same code on a M1 Mac (macOS Big Sur, Python 3.9.5) and on a Debian 11 (Python 3.9.2) and while the "Bye!" messages all printed at the same time on my Debian machine, they printed consecutively with 1 second delay between each print on my M1 Mac.